# Trying to implement ContextAPI with React functional components

Tags: reactjs, use-state, react-functional-component, codepen, react-context

Trying to build a simple expense tracker and wanted to share the monthly income state to all the components within the application...Having trouble setting up ContextAPI with my functional components..any suggestions on what's wrong with my code? (codepen is telling me it cannot read property 'props')

```js
function App(){
  return(
    <ExpenseNumbersProvider>
      <div className="flex-container">
        <div className="left">
          <Input /> 
          <Graph />
        </div>
        <ExpenseLog />
      </div>
    </ExpenseNumbersProvider>
  )
};
```

```js
function ExpenseNumbersProvider (){
  const ExpenseNumbers = createContext();
      
  const [monthly,setMonthly] = useState(0);
     
  return(
    <ExpenseNumbers.Provider value={{monthly}}>
      {this.props.children}
    </ExpenseNumbers.Provider>
  )
}
```

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/anthonybp12/pen/JjNqEeG

Answer (score 0):

You are using `this` in the context of a functional component. Replace `this.props.children` with `props.children` ... you also need to pass `props` in as a param for `ExpenseNumbersProviders`

```
function ExpenseNumbersProvider (props){
  const ExpenseNumbers = createContext();
  
  const [monthly,setMonthly] = useState(0);
  
  return(
    <ExpenseNumbers.Provider value={{monthly}}>
      {props.children}
    </ExpenseNumbers.Provider>
  )
}
```